# VBA Macro to assess cells in a variable range of columns and rows and output a binary number in a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following code:

```
Dim TrimThreshold As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim CurrentColumn As String
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data HUB")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

TrimThreshold = Sheets("sheet2").Range("B3").Value
Counter = 0
CurrentColumn = "B2"

Sheets("Data HUB").Activate
For Each cell In Range(CurrentColumn, Range(CurrentColumn).End(xlDown))
    If cell.Value >= TrimThreshold Then
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("C3").Offset(Counter, 0).Value = 1
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Else
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("C3").Offset(Counter, 0).Value = 0
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

This code successfully works for 1 column but is there anyway to assess for a variable range of both columns and rows? For instance, my data may look like the attached picture:

[image: sheet]

but the columns and rows may be variable between data worksheets (the columns and rows will always be equal within a single worksheet though!)

The final output will be a binary number (either 1 or 0) in the next tab of the worksheet determined if the value of the cell is greather than the threshold value entered in a cell (sheet2.cell"B3" in this case).

Thank you!

Comment: Your `TrimThreshold`, is this always gona be in "B3"? or is it current column in row 3?

Comment: Yes the TrimThreshold will always be in B3 of sheet 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be self-explaining:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

  With Sheets("Data HUB")

    Dim inRange As Range
    Set inRange = .Range("B2")
    Set inRange = .Range(inRange.End(xlToRight), inRange.End(xlDown))

    Dim wsOut As Worksheet
    Set wsOut = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

    Dim TrimThreshold As Long
    TrimThreshold = wsOut.Range("B3").Value

    Dim outRange As Range
    Set outRange = wsOut.Range("C3").Resize(inRange.Rows.Count, inRange.Columns.Count)

    outRange.Value = .Evaluate("(" & inRange.Address & ">=" & TrimThreshold & ")*1")

  End With

End Sub
```

If you still have any questions, just ask :)

Comment: This works great! Thank you.

Lastly, is it possible to sum up the binary values at the top of the respective columns? 

I've tried using something like:
    Range("C3:D" & Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row).Name = "TotalAmount"
    Range("C2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TotalAmount)

but this won't iterate across the columns and doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: @cgriffin As row 2 does not change, you could simply insert for C2 `=SUM(C3:C9999)` and copy to the right as you need it... if the size is variable, simply set formatting to `0;0;;@` (this will hide zero values)

Comment: Thank you again for the help!